# Lua: getting the latest line in external txt file

Tags: lua

I am having a lua function to reading and writing a txt file, I need every time lua write in at a new line instead of replacing the previous write in. How do I do that? Do I need to read in and get the lines 1st every time before I write in?

Here is my code:

```
local function FileOutput(name)
    local f = io.open(name, "w+")
    local meta = {
        __call = function(t, str) f:write(str .. '\n') end,
        __gc = function() f:close() end
    }
    return setmetatable({}, meta)
end

function writeRec()
LOG("writing")
local testfile = FileOutput(getScriptDirectory()..'/textOutput.txt') 
testfile('oh yes!')
testfile = nil
end
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that `__gc` works with tables, as the ref man says :"Garbage *userdata* with a field __gc in their metatables are not collected immediately by the garbage collector"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `a+` instead of `w+`?

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.open

Comment: Oh yes! How silly i am, i forgot the check on the writing modes.Thank you, man!